# Relationship between rate of reaction and pressure

Tags: physical-chemistry, kinetics, gas-laws

Given the equation

$$\ce{A(g) + B(g) → C(g) + D(g)}$$

with reaction rate given by

$$v = k[\ce{A}]^2$$

How can I prove that reaction rate goes up with pressure? I tried substituting $k$ for $Ae^{-E_A/(RT)}$ which leaves me with

$$v = Ae^{-\frac{E_A}{RT}}[A]^2$$

If I use

$$PV = nRT \implies RT = \frac{1}{n}PV \implies RT = \frac{P}{C}$$

I end up with this:

$$v = Ae^{-E_A\frac{C}{P}}[A]^2$$

This shows there is a relation, but I don't know what to do with the concentration $C$, or whether it was correct to plug in the ideal gas law in the first place.  Any help?

Comment: Pressure is directly proportional to concentration via the ideal gas law, so the rate $\sim kp^2$ .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exponential term in the Arrhenius equation does not imply reaction with other molecules. It applies to ready to react unstable adduct, about to overcome the energy barrier $E_a$ to form the product.
The concentration of this adduct is driven by concentration of reagents and therefore by the pressure.

Therefore the reaction rate equation implicitly involve 2 multiplicative terms:

1. Concentration of reagent adduct

   $$\mathrm{const}\cdot [A]^2 = \mathrm{const}\cdot \left(\frac{p_{\rm A}}{RT}\right)^2$$
2. Probability the adduct reaches the reaction energy barrier, from the Boltzmann distribution:

   $$\exp{\left(-\frac{E_A}{RT}\right)}$$

By other words, the constant $A$ in your equation

$$v = A \exp\left(-\frac{E_A}{RT}\right)$$

implicitly involves concentration, respectively pressure of the reagents.